# Is there a way to toggle a node in Chord diagram amChart via API?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Chord diagram enables user to click a node and toggle it's inactive state. See preview.

[image: Chord diagram with some disabled nodes]

Is there a way to disable this node via an api? I'd like to disable some nodes at the same time with a JS function.

Answer (score 1):

Like most objects in the chart, each node has [`show`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chordnode/#show_method) and [`hide`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chordnode/#hide_method) methods that allow you to toggle their appearance. The chord chart stores each node in a [`Dictionary`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dictionary/), so you'll want to use [`getKey`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dictionary/#getKey_method) to access the node by its name and then call `hide`:

```
chart.nodes.getKey('Senica').hide()
```

Ideally, you'll want to call this after the node dictionary is completely populated, such as during the `datavalidated` event.

```
chart.events.on('datavalidated', function() {
  chart.nodes.getKey('Senica').hide()
})
```

Demo:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.ChordDiagram);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0;

chart.data = [
    { from: "A", to: "D", value: 10 },
    { from: "B", to: "D", value: 8 },
    { from: "B", to: "E", value: 4 },
    { from: "B", to: "C", value: 2 },
    { from: "C", to: "E", value: 14 },
    { from: "E", to: "D", value: 8 },
    { from: "C", to: "A", value: 4 },
    { from: "G", to: "A", value: 7 },
    { from: "D", to: "B", value: 1 }
];

chart.dataFields.fromName = "from";
chart.dataFields.toName = "to";
chart.dataFields.value = "value";

// make nodes draggable
var nodeTemplate = chart.nodes.template;
nodeTemplate.readerTitle = "Click to show/hide or drag to rearrange";
nodeTemplate.showSystemTooltip = true;
nodeTemplate.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.pointer

chart.events.on('datavalidated', function() {
  chart.nodes.getKey('A').hide();
  chart.nodes.getKey('B').hide();
  chart.nodes.getKey('D').hide();
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: I found that there is a hidden parameter  
`chart.nodes.template.propertyFields.hidden = "disabled";`  

for that you just pass disabled: true in the data  

`{ from: "A", to: "B", value: 3, disabled: true },  
{ from: "C", to: "D", value: 6 }`

Comment: Yes, that's another method as well if you want to do it through data.